# Insert into select from another database table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

I am having issues when trying to insert records from a database table into another database table, I wonder how to execute the query with one connection string while I have two different connection strings related to the two database, my code is shown below.

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
insert.Connection = conn2; // conn2 is the connection of the second database
insert.Parameters.Add("@Réf", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row["N° Caisse"];// row is a row of a datagrid
insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Caisse([N° Caisse], [Date d'Ouverture], [Date de Clôture], [Fond de Caisse], [Vendeur]) SELECT * FROM Database1.Caisse WHERE Databse1.Caisse.[N° Caisse] = @Réf";
// notice that both database have a table named "Caisse" so I'm inserting into 'Caisse of the second database the records selected from "Caisse" of the first table

conn2.Open();
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn2.Close();
```

I get this error message :

> Invalid object name 'Database1.Caisse'.

I am using Visual Studio WPF as IDE

Comment: What if you tried "Database1.dbo.Caisse"

Comment: @level3looper same thing I get 'Invalid object name 'Database1.dbo.Caisse'

Comment: Maybe a different schema or mabe permissions?  How about trying 'Database1..Caisse'

Comment: You need to make sure that you use the correct schema @SaberCHETIOUI

Comment: Can you execute the following command on database1 to see what it returns for your schema?   [SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'Caisse']

Comment: "two different connection strings" - sounds like either you need a linked server or pull back the results into a local object and insert using the second connection string...or is it three connection strings? That is not real clear either.  Your error simply indicates that table does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, it can be done this way:

```
 conn.Open();
 string database1 = conn.Database.ToString();
 SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
 insert.Connection = conn2;             
 insert.Parameters.Add("@Réf", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row["N° Caisse"];
 insert.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Caisse([N° Caisse],[Date d'Ouverture],[Date de Clôture],[Fond de Caisse],[Vendeur]) SELECT*FROM ["+database1+"].dbo.Caisse x WHERE  x.[N° Caisse]=@Réf";
 conn2.Open();
 insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn2.Close();
```

the target database can be accessed with the SqlConnection.Database property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert.CommandText = "insert into Caisse ([N° Caisse], [Date d'Ouverture], [Date de Clôture], [Fond de Caisse], [Vendeur]) select * from Database1.dbo.Caisse x where x.[N° Caisse] = @Réf";
```

There is another *dirty* solution that may works:

```
insert.CommandText = "use Archive; create table ##TempTb (a int,b datetime, c datetime, d money, e int); insert into ##TempTb select ([N° Caisse], [Date d'Ouverture], [Date de Clôture], [Fond de Caisse], [Vendeur]) from Caisse where [N° Caisse] = @Réf; Use Database1; insert into Caisse ([N° Caisse], [Date d'Ouverture], [Date de Clôture], [Fond de Caisse], [Vendeur]) select * from ##TempTb;";
```

Comment: not working, I still get 'Invalid object name 'Database1.dbo.Caisse'

Comment: Is `Database1` the real name of the 2nd database? is it on the *same* SQL Server? You can try: `exec sp_helpdb` on the server to see the real name

Comment: Yes, Database1 is the real name and it on the same instance, to clear, I'm using the localDB media of sqlserver

Comment: Could you try to open a query thought SSME at the 2nd database, like `select top 1 * from Database1.dbo.Caisse` to check the issue?

Comment: I think you were right, the issue is in the name, I tried using queries without declaring the databases names like " select from table" and it works fine, but when I write "select from Database.dbo.table" it send me the message 'Invalid object name 'Database1.dbo.Caisse' , and this apply to both databases in my solution Database1 and Archive. But my query that I wrote in my posted question uses both Databases tables, so how can I separate tables without declaring databases's names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Caisse([N° Caisse],[Date d'Ouverture],[Date de Clôture],[Fond de Caisse],[Vendeur]) SELECT [N° Caisse],[Date d'Ouverture],[Date de Clôture],[Fond de Caisse],[Vendeur] FROM Database1.Caisse WHERE Databse1.Caisse.[N° Caisse]=@Réf";
```

Comment: still not working, I get 'Invalid object name 'Database1.dbo.Caisse'

Comment: @mlamsarf  your query is syntactically incorrect since it does not include a schema name. In addition, code only answers are discouraged since they do little to "teach". Lastly we already no that adding the database name to the table reference does not work for OP - please read the thread before posting to avoid duplicative suggestions, comments, and questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CurrentDatabase.CurrentSchema.Caisse([N° Caisse],[Date d'Ouverture],[Date de Clôture],[Fond de Caisse],[Vendeur]) SELECT * FROM Database1.Schema.Caisse WHERE Databse1.Schema.Caisse.[N° Caisse]=@Réf"
```

- `CurrentDatabase.CurrentSchema.Caisse` is the target table.
- `Database1.Schema.Caisse` is the source table

Note that for the `SELECT` statement, better to use the columns names instead of `*`, but it will work if the columns returned by `SELECT *` are the same for the target table.

But, you may check your connection, cause I think you just connect to `Archive` database. In this case you need to connect to both databases, get the data from the `Dabase1.Caisse` and then insert it to the `Archive.Caisse` table.

Comment: I tried to include the schema's name which is suggested in the first answer, I used dbo which is the default name of newly created database.

Comment: thanks for the effort, I tried it in SSMS, and it does'nt recognize 'Database1' as the name of the database but it propose [C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\SELLPOINT\SELLPOINT\DATABASE1.MDF].dbo.Caisse which worked juste fine. so do I have to indicate the full path of the database then?

Comment: Did you see the database `Database1` in the object explorer of SSMS? Are you sure the database attached?

Comment: No, not Database1 but C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\SELLPOINT\SELLPOINT\DATABASE1.MDF is what I get in the explorer, and yes I joined the Database1.

Comment: `USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseName] ON 
    (FILENAME = N'FullPath.mdf'),
    (FILENAME = N'FullPath.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH
GO` That what you need to do @SaberCHETIOUI and all will be fine.

Comment: I dont get it, why do I have to create a new database, I already have one, and it has tables within it, but I can't assign a name for it, SSMS assigned a default name for it when I joined it, and it's the path.Database1.mdf, but what I'd like to know is how to call it with a query in visual studio?